# Optimizing sql query to find number of non unique values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone have an idea how to optmize the query below as it is taking quite some time:

```
select count(*) from 
(select field1
from table
group by field1
having count(distinct field1) <> count(field1)) AS Q1
```

The query is used to find the number of non unique values in a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `INDEX` on column `field1`, eg

```
ALTER TABLE tableNAME ADD INDEX (field1)
```

- [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Without indexes, the performance will still be low even if you ave a good query.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the number of non-unique values, use:

```
select count(*)
from (select field1
      from table
       group by field1
       having count(*) > 1
      ) t
```

And, yes, an index on `table.field1` will speed this up.

If you want the values, use:

```
select field1
from table
group by field1
having count(*) > 1
```